# Comparing strings in qt doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compare two strings with default in Qt but it always fails. it's always false

the statement if group == default, goes to s.beginGroup, however the group is called Default. I don't know where is the problem, that's so weird.

```
 foreach (const QString &group, s.childGroups()) {
        if(group =="Default")
            continue;
        s.beginGroup(group);
        Profile *profile = new Profile();
        profile->setObjectName(group);
        profile->load(s);
        s.endGroup();

        m_Profiles << profile;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `foreach` in Qt resolves to the following:

```
#  define Q_FOREACH(variable, container)                                \
for (QForeachContainer<QT_FOREACH_DECLTYPE(container)>  _container_((container)); \
 _container_.control && _container_.i != _container_.e;         \
 ++_container_.i, _container_.control ^= 1)                     \
    for (variable = *_container_.i; _container_.control; _container_.control = 0)
```

so as you can see there are two `for` loops, possibly the continue keyword does not continue with the one you would like to, but the inner one.

**Edit** after @chi's comment

There is a nice explanation in the Qt header file:

```
// Explanation of the control word:
//  - it's initialized to 1
//  - that means both the inner and outer loops start
//  - if there were no breaks, at the end of the inner loop, it's set to 0, which
//    causes it to exit (the inner loop is run exactly once)
//  - at the end of the outer loop, it's inverted, so it becomes 1 again, allowing
//    the outer loop to continue executing
//  - if there was a break inside the inner loop, it will exit with control still
//    set to 1; in that case, the outer loop will invert it to 0 and will exit too
```

as you can see there is no mention of the `continue` only the break. And there is no mention of the `continue` on the `foreach` documentation page either: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword only the break is presented.

Comment: Wow. The logic underlying `_container_.control` is ... interesting.

Comment: No matter what, a `continue` or a `break` will exit the current block, so it doesn't fix the original problem. It won't go to `s.beginGroup`!

Comment: `continue` and `break` work just fine within `Q_FOREACH`. Maybe they're broken in the abomination that is the implementation that works on VC6, but then everything else is broken there already, so let's not dwell on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiler is C++11 enabled you better switch to ranged-for instead:

```
for (const QString& group : s.childGroups())
{ ... }
```

Ranged-for loops support `continue` keyword as expected

Also, `CONFIG += c++11` must be added to a *.pro file of your project

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main() {
   auto const kDefault = QStringLiteral("Default");
   QStringList groups{"a", kDefault, "b"};
   QStringList output;
   // C++11
   for (auto group : groups) {
      if(group == kDefault)
         continue;
      Q_ASSERT(group != kDefault);
      output << group;
   }
   // C++98
   foreach (const QString &group, groups) {
      if(group == kDefault)
         continue;
      Q_ASSERT(group != kDefault);
      output << group;
   }
   Q_ASSERT(output == (QStringList{"a", "b", "a", "b"}));
}
```

Your problem is elsewhere, or your debugger is lying to you.